# data is not saving mailvalidation in models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am creating signup page with email verification but I am getting type error mailvalidation() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id'

views.py

```
def signup(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    username=request.POST['username']
    email=request.POST['email']
    password=request.POST['password']
    cpassword=request.POST['cpassword']
    userdetails(name=username,email=email,password=password).save()
    user = userdetails.objects.get(email=email)
    token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
    #print(user.id)
    #print(user.email)
    #print(user.name)
    #print(token)
    mailvalidation(user_id=user.id, user_email=user.email, user_name=user.name, key=token).save()
    sendmail(email, token)
    return HttpResponse('We have sent a email verification please check your email')
return render(request,'credentials/register.html')
```

models.py

```
class userdetails(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    valid_email=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(default=today)
    class Meta:
        db_table='user_details'

class mailvalidation(models.Model):
    user_id=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_email=models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    key=models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table='mail_validation'
```

I am getting a error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`user_id` used in mailvalidation should `ForeignKey`

So, You can change this

`user_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)`

to

`user = models.ForeignKey(userdetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Here `user` field will be repested as `user_id` so no need to add `_id` to user.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Abhishek Patel just i changed mailvalidation to validationmail and it works fine